# Unable to locate package ubuntu-extras-keyring

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install the `ubuntu-extras-keyring` package and this is the output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-extras-keyring
```

On the Ubuntu Packages website I discovered that the package is not available for my release, Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I install it now? Is another package available?

Comment: If it is not available it is not available so no you can not install it. What does it do and why do you need it?

Comment: There is no such package for Ubuntu after 14.04. "How can I install it now, and another packet doesn't avilable?" You don't. There is no need for it so why do you feel like you need to install it?

Comment: It is still available for manual download from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-extras-keyring/ . Why do you think you need it?

Answer (score 3):

It appears you're attempting to install a package that isn't available anymore.

As you look for software you have to pay close attention to which version of the OS it is aimed for.
If there is no direct mention of the OS version, then look for the AGE of the information (e.g. "posted ").

Old versions of software has a tendency to not work with a recent OS distribution.

Old software may get replaced entire by something "new", or the setup might require a different style than what you're reading about.

How quickly that happens - and the "severity" of it - depends on changes taking place;
e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS are quite different in setup, due to decisions taken by those involved in the process of creating the later distribution.
Between those there are several actual differences; one such (not related to the Q) is the fact that python2 was dropped entirely. Packages relying solely on python 2 will not work in 20.04.